# Remove row in array by a condition of frequency of keys in first column

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array

```
A=[[   1    3  256 1556]
 [   2    3  507 1221]
 [   3    3  723 1192]
.....
 [7558 2103  793  763]
 [7574 2103  188 1443]
 [7575 2103  713  757]]
```

i need to remove rows by conditioning on frequencies of values in 1st column. For example if count(1)<8, I need to remove all the row that contain 1st column value as 1. Can you please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show your attempts and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a numpy array

```
threshold = 8
# count each unique element in the first column
u, c = np.unique(A[:,0], return_counts=True)
# only keep the rows that occur more than threshold number of times
A[np.isin(A[:,0], u[c>=threshold])]
```